# How to make a count down timer to count down to a specific time in a batch file

Tags: batch-file, timer, countdown

I am trying to create a batch file timer that will display and count down to 9:00 am from when the batch file is executed.

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off

rem Get number of seconds to wait from now until 9:00 hrs
for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=:." %%a in ("%time%") do set /A H=%%a, M=1%%b-100, S=1%%c-100, Nine=9
if %H% geq 9 set /A Nine+=24
set /A seconds=((Nine-H)*60-M)*60-S

timeout /T %seconds%
```

Comment: Thanks, is there a way for it to be displayed in min:sec?